# Moving variables from Javascript to HTML and saving variables so they can be used in other functions

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble with transferring variables from **Javascript** to **HTML**, as well as storing the outcome of a **Javascript** function as a variable. Here is my code that I will explain below:

Inside my **HTML** document:

```
<hmtl>

<title> Japanese </title>

<head>
<script src="japanese.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="japanese.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="title">
Japanese
</div>

<button onclick="process()">Random</button>
<br>
<div id="number"> </div>
<div id="english"> </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Inside my **Javascript** document:

```
function random() {
    var integer = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (3)));
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = integer;
};

function searchE() {
    var English = englishID[integer];
    document.getElementById('english').innerHTML = English;
};

function process() {
    random();
    searchE();
};

var englishID [
    "add",
    "answer",
    "arrive"
];
```

I think there might be something wrong with how I set the English variable, beacuse before I added the `searchE`function to the code the random number between 0 and 2 displayed.

Thanks for your time.

Update! Changed the `searchE` function to the following:

```
function searchE() {
    var integer = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (3)));
    var English = englishID[integer];
    document.getElementById('english').innerHTML = English;
```

However, the code still doesn't work :(

Comment: `integer` is not in scope inside `searchE`.

Comment: It still doesn't give out an output even when I add it to the search E function.

Comment: Adding it to the searche function won't help, you need to make it global. Declare it outside of the function like englishid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to passing a variable from a function to another is returning the result of fn1 and passing that value to the function fn2:

**For example:**

```
function a () { 
   var integer = 1 + 4;
   // Some stuff with integer

   return integer;
}

function b (resultA){
    console.log(resultA);
}

b(a()); // Here the result of 'a' is passed to the function 'b'
```

```js
function random() {
  var integer = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (3)));
  document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = integer;
  
  return integer;
};

function searchE(integer) {
  var English = englishID[integer];
  document.getElementById('english').innerHTML = English; 
};

function process() {  
  searchE(random());
};

var englishID = [
  "add",
  "answer",
  "arrive"
];
```

```html
<div class="title">
  Japanese
</div>

<button onclick="process()">Random</button>
<br>
<div id="number"> </div>
<div id="english"> </div>
```

Comment: I tried editing the code exactly like you typed up and I still didn't recieve an output from clicking the button.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the number you put in the document and use it in `searchE`, you'll have to select the element again and extract its text:

```
function searchE() {
  const integerFromDocument = Number(document.querySelector('#number').textContent);
  var English = englishID[integerFromDocument];
  document.getElementById('english').textContent = English;
}
```

Only use `innerHTML` when you're deliberately inserting/getting HTML markup; otherwise, `textContent` is faster, safer, and more predictable if you're only intending to deal with text.

Snippet:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', process);
function random() {
    var integer = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (3)));
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = integer;
}

function searchE() {
  const integerFromDocument = Number(document.querySelector('#number').textContent);
  var English = englishID[integerFromDocument];
  document.getElementById('english').textContent = English;
}

function process() {
    random();
    searchE();
}

var englishID = [
    "add",
    "answer",
    "arrive"
];
```

```html
<div class="title">
Japanese
</div>
<button>Random</button>
<br>
<div id="number"> </div>
<div id="english"> </div>
```

Comment: I attempted changing the "searchE()" function to what you suggested by it still didn't give an output.

Comment: You had a number of syntax errors you have to fix as well. See snippet in edit above.

Answer (score 1):

You have some variables that are scoped inside functions that you are treating as globals.You could initialize integer at the very top, outside of the function. I would recommend though having two functions that return the integer and English respectively and then call those in process and set up your innerHTML in there.

Answer (score 1):

your code is actually breaking. it is not working because there is no assignment operator for englishID.

make the following change

#### from

```
var englishID [
  "add",
  "answer",
  "arrive"
];
```

#### to

```
var englishID = [
  "add",
  "answer",
  "arrive"
];
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried everything else that other people were saying but in the end I also needed to add an equals sign.

Comment: @AlexanderJephtha yep. everything you did was right. you just needed to add an equals sign to englishID